# The "Return false" instruction works intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div element (id=ecover) in my sidebar> clicking on it reveals another div (id=ebook_form). The jQuery code for this is below. Because there is a href link involved, I use return false after the code for displaying the hidden div.

It used to work perfectly, but now for some reason, it sometimes works and sometimes the "return false" seems not to work.

```
jQuery('#ecover').click(function(){     

    jQuery("#ebook_form").slideToggle('fast');      

    var ecover_vertical_position = jQuery('#ecover').offset();

    ecover_vertical_position = ecover_vertical_position.top;

    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ecover_vertical_position }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');

return false;

});
```

Comment: Open your console and check for errors when it stops working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return false` is a bad way of preventing the default action. This is for three main reasons:

1. It has to come at the end of the function. This is not always desirable behaviour. It is often nicer to prevent the default behaviour at the beginning of the handler, or indeed to have the flexibility to have it elsewhere. You can achieve this with `event.preventDefault()`.
2. It prevents other event handlers further up the DOM tree from being fired. This may be desirable: if so, you can use `event.stopPropagation()`. But there's no reason to assume that the two should always go together.
3. If the code has any errors that cause Javascript to throw an error and leave the function, the `return false` will never be reached, so the default action will take place. If we put `event.preventDefault()` at the top of the function, this won't happen. This is particularly bad, as in this instance, where the default behaviour involves changing pages, so the error console is cleared and you can't see what error occurred.

So this code, for instance, will always prevent the default behaviour:

```
jQuery('#ecover').click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery("#ebook_form").slideToggle('fast');      

    var ecover_vertical_position = jQuery('#ecover').offset();

    ecover_vertical_position = ecover_vertical_position.top;

    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: ecover_vertical_position }, 500, 'easeInOutExpo');
});
```

This won't solve the actual problem, which is that your code is throwing an error. My guess is that something is going wrong with the `offset` function, so the object has no `top` property, but I can't quite work out how this would occur given that the event handler is fired on that element's `click` event. But in any case, once the default behaviour has stopped, you will be able to determine the error using the browser console.